# grouping column in google data studio

Tags: grouping, pie-chart, looker-studio

I have example data:

customer_list:

```
Name     suburb
Cersei   king-landing
Jamie    king-landing
Jon      winterfell
Arya     winterfell
Sansa    winterfell
Dany     westeros
```

in google-data studio, what is the best way if I want to create pie chart based on total people live in suburb.

So, from my example it should be

```
Winterfell 50% of pie chart
king-landing 33 % of pie chart
westeros     16% of pie chart
```

I have some research, such as
https://datarunsdeep.com.au/blog/custom-content-grouping-data-studio

but it doesnt make sense to me, because we need to create each group. what if I have 1000++ suburbs?

I have just started to look into this product today by the way. Apologise if I don't know too much about this yet.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

- ***Chart Type***: [Pie Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7187587)
- ***Dimension***: `suburb`
- ***Metric***: `suburb` (Aggregation: [Count](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207))

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/25447d95-83d2-44c0-bac1-5741252ee973) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking at DataStudio for the first time, so apologies if this is off the mark, but would the following work?

Click 'Add a Metric', then 'Create New Metric' (named whatever you want - for this example a nice intuitive `suburb_count`) and have this set to `COUNT(suburb)`.

Then, create a pie chart with `suburb` as the dimension and use the `suburb_count` as the metric to measure this against?

Hope this gets you in the right direction. Let me know - interested to see if this worked!